# ServiceNotFoundException when trying to use TYPO3 12 ActionController

Tags: php, typo3, autoload

When Trying to register my DummyController to use it as a Typo3 Plugin, I get the following error:
`ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "MyVendorName\Typo3StarterSitepackage\Controller\DummyController"`

I tried to do everything like the documentation states, and also did some research, bud was unable to resolve the issue. Here is my code:

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendorName\Typo3StarterSitepackage\Controller;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class DummyController extends ActionController
{
    public function dummyListAction(): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->htmlResponse();
    }
}
```

My DummyRepository.php:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendorName\Typo3StarterSitepackage\Domain\Repository;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface;

class DummyRepository extends Repository
{
    // this already has some default functions, like findAll(), inherited from the Repository class.
}
```

My Services.yaml file:

```
services:
  # general settings
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  MyVendorName\Typo3StarterSitepackage\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'
```

My ext_localconf.php:

```
<?php

use MyVendorName\Typo3StarterSitepackage\Controller\DummyController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility;

defined('TYPO3') or die('Access denied.');
/***************
 * Add default RTE configuration
 */
// $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['typo3_starter_sitepackage'] = 'EXT:typo3_starter_sitepackage/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml';

/***************
 * PageTS
 */
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:typo3_starter_sitepackage/Configuration/TsConfig/Page/All.tsconfig">');

ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'typo3_starter_sitepackage',
    'DummyList',
    [DummyController::class => 'dummyList'],
);
```

With this code I am able to select the Plugin through the Typo3 Backend, but then the ServiceNotFoundException is thrown. I am aware that the Controller doesn't return anything right now, but I think that's not the cause of this issue.

I am working on Windows using XAMPP with PHP 8.2, Typo3 12.4.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. There were two main problems with my installation. Here is how I fixed it:

- I had some issues with PHP 8.2, mainly some doctrine errors, and eventually switched to PHP 8.1.
- The composer.json file that was created after initializing my project with the command `composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution example-project-directory "^12"` came with predefined "typo3-cms-scripts", where `typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure` was called. This didn't work for me. Instead I set `typo3 cache:flush` and `typo3 cache:warmup`.

After that, I deleted my composer.lock file and my vendor folder and freshly installed the composer packages (this might not have been necessary). The post autoload dump script, that now clears the typo3 caches,  ran without errors and the ServiceNotFoundException went away.

Comment: Simple thing - don't blame, contribute a better documentation. TYPO3 v12 is compatible, and even with PHP8.3 and quite a lot of people are using it with that version (already v11). But as it's quite a hard code base the one or other place can exist which may fail. If you have concrete php version related issues report them on https://forge.typo3.org. What do you mean the composer.json file came with ? TYPO3 core don't ship a composer json with that - or are you talking about the base-distribution ? Than add a github isse in the corresponding repository. (Many do not use the base distribution)

Comment: @StefanBürk thanks for the input. I changed the solution to sound more neutral. I also clarified where I got the composer.json file from. The very simple thing of contributing to the documentation will be done once I have some more time to spare.

Comment: Executed exactly and cannot find any scripts in the generated composer.json - so this is really weired. See here the gist of created composer.json using the command from README.md and copy&pasted your stated command  https://gist.github.com/sbuerk/d8c38fb425b20e4a0a83ba18350008d5

Answer (score 0):

Casual errors related to these cases are:

- Recheck exactly the casing of the class and namespace, in Services.yaml, the file and the corresponding composer.json autoload namespace (+ext_emconf.php autoload section for legacy mode).
- Check that you really has not excluded the controller

and try to rebuild caches

```bash
vendor/bin/typo3 cache:flush
vendor/bin/typo3 cache:warump
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I run "vendor/bin/typo3 cache:flush" I get the error Class "mysqli" not found in C:\Users\myuser\typo3-12-dummy\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\Mysqli\Driver.php:37 although mysqli is enabled when I check it with phpinfo().

I also re-checked all my casings, but cannot find discrepencies. It looks like this in my ext_emconf:

'MyVendorName\\Typo3StarterSitepackage\\' => 'Classes',

Comment: Maybe different php binaries ? Beside that, cli and web can have different sets of extensions loaded and available. Eventually a wrong version has been used (can happen on systems with multiple php binaries available).

Comment: I checked my PATH and which version was used, and couldn't find any discrepency between my CLI version and my server version. However, it is possible that I made a mistake, and switching to php 8.1 just evened my environment so to speak.